# Close modal when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

I was able to make my modal close when clicking on the x icon and when pressing the escape button. How can I also make it close when clicking outside the modal (i.e. the page's body?) Thanks

```
document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger").forEach((trigger) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(trigger.dataset.modal);
    const closeBtn = modal.querySelector(".modal-close");
    function open() {
        modal.classList.add("show-modal");
        trigger.blur();
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", escapeClose);
    }
    function close() {
        modal.classList.remove("show-modal");
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", escapeClose);
    }
    function escapeClose(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            close();
        }
    }
    trigger.addEventListener("click", open);
    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", close);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

```
document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger").forEach((trigger) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(trigger.dataset.modal);
    const closeBtn = modal.querySelector(".modal-close");
    function open(event) {
        modal.classList.add("show-modal");
        trigger.blur();
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", escapeClose);
        modal.addEventListener("click", outsideClose);
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    function close() {
        modal.classList.remove("show-modal");
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", escapeClose);
        modal.removeEventListener("click", outsideClose);
    }
    function escapeClose(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            close();
        }
    }

    function outsideClose(event) {
        if (
            event.target === modal ||
            event.target.classList.contains("close-modal")
        ) {
            close();
        }
    }

    trigger.addEventListener("click", open);
    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", close);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this close the modal if the user clicks within the modal element? Should it not be `event.target != modal` instead?

Comment: That was an issue for me indeed it took me a while to figure out, so in the modal variable I have a div which serves as a background. So if the modal gets a click, and if the target is itself, it means that I did not click in the modal content but instead on the background, so I close the modal. So if I do `event.target != modal` it does the opposite: closes when I click on the modal, not when I click on the background this works but there's probably a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I will post my very simple and generic solution whih uses the logical (!not) operator to check if the click is inside or outside of the modal.

Answer (score 2):

I like this solution, that I probably found here on Stackoverflow:

```
// Close modal on outside click

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let clickInside = modal.contains(e.target)

  if (!clickInside) {
     modal.classList.remove('show')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest(trigger.dataset.modal) == null) {
    close();
  }
})
```

This will query the closest() method on whatever item was clicked. Closest() traverses UP the dom from where it starts. So if you click outside of the modal, it would return a null value. If you click an item within the modal, it will return the modal itself. You should be able to assume that if the returned value is null, that the click came from outside of the modal.

**Additional Info about closest()**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the style directly with the event listener.

```
window.onclick = (e) => {
    if (e.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }        
}
```