# How to close a popup modal when clicking outside of the modal while being able to arrow down radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dialog, modal-dialog

I am trying to add functionality to close my modal when a user clicks outside of it.  This solution works

```
const googleMissingInfoModal = document.getElementById('recommended-changes-modal');
googleMissingInfoModal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const dialogDimensions = googleMissingInfoModal.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (e.clientX < dialogDimensions.left || e.clientX > dialogDimensions.right || e.clientY < dialogDimensions.top || e.clientY > dialogDimensions.bottom) {
    googleMissingInfoModal.close();
  }
});
```

However, it messes with the accessibility of the modal as a user using a keyboard when hitting the up/down arrow keys it closes the modal.  My modal has radio buttons so a user needs to be able to use the arrow keys to navigate the form.

I have also tried the suggestions here, [Close modal when clicking outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477953/close-modal-when-clicking-outside-of-it), but when I tried these the modal would not close when clicking outside of it.

This is my modal:

```
                 <dialog id="recommended-changes-modal" class="google-validation-modal">
                     <span class="google-modal-close">&times;</span>
                     <form method="dialog" class="modal-form">
                         <fieldset class="google-modal-fieldset">
                             <legend>
                                 <span class="google-modal-title">Confirm your address</span>
                                 Review the recommended changes
                             </legend>
                             <div class="modal-radio-container">
                                 <input type="radio" id="user-entered-address" name="address" />
                                 <label for="user-entered-address" class="modal-label">What you entered:</label>
                                 <div id="patient-address-content" class="modal-address">
                                     <div id="user-address-street"></div>
                                     <div id="user-address-city-state-zip"></div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-radio-container">
                                 <input type="radio" id="recommended-address" name="address" />
                                 <label for="recommended-address" class="modal-label">Recommended:</label>
                                 <div id="google-address-content" class="modal-address">
                                     <div id="google-address-street"></div>
                                     <div id="google-address-city-state-zip"></div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </fieldset>
                         <div class="google-validation-messages">
                             <p class="red-text">Please select an address</p>
                         </div>
                         <div class="button-container">
                             <button type="button" id="confirm-address-button" class="confirm-address-button">Confirm</button>
                         </div>
                     </form>
                 </dialog>
```

Comment: but which radio buttons are you talking about? there are none in the lines of code you present
nothing is clear in your message, reread the SO guidelines: [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specialy : [how to provide a minimal & reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong modal in my question.  I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the arrow keys issue, you can ensure it is a mouse event:

```
const googleMissingInfoModal = document.getElementById('recommended-changes-modal');

googleMissingInfoModal.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const dialogDimensions = googleMissingInfoModal.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (e.clientX < dialogDimensions.left || e.clientX > dialogDimensions.right || e.clientY < dialogDimensions.top || e.clientY > dialogDimensions.bottom) {
    googleMissingInfoModal.close();
  }
});
```

Below is a working example:

```js
const googleMissingInfoModal = document.getElementById('recommended-changes-modal');

// Open the modal for testing
googleMissingInfoModal.showModal();

googleMissingInfoModal.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const dialogDimensions = googleMissingInfoModal.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (e.clientX < dialogDimensions.left || e.clientX > dialogDimensions.right ||
    e.clientY < dialogDimensions.top || e.clientY > dialogDimensions.bottom) {
    googleMissingInfoModal.close();
  }
});
```

```css
.google-validation-modal {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.modal-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="recommended-changes-modal" class="google-validation-modal">
  <span class="google-modal-close">&times;</span>
  <form method="dialog" class="modal-form">
    <fieldset class="google-modal-fieldset">
      <legend>
        <span class="google-modal-title">Confirm your address</span> Review the recommended changes
      </legend>
      <div class="modal-radio-container">
        <input type="radio" id="user-entered-address" name="address" />
        <label for="user-entered-address" class="modal-label">What you entered:</label>
        <div id="patient-address-content" class="modal-address">
          <div id="user-address-street"></div>
          <div id="user-address-city-state-zip"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-radio-container">
        <input type="radio" id="recommended-address" name="address" />
        <label for="recommended-address" class="modal-label">Recommended:</label>
        <div id="google-address-content" class="modal-address">
          <div id="google-address-street"></div>
          <div id="google-address-city-state-zip"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="google-validation-messages">
      <p class="red-text">Please select an address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="button" id="confirm-address-button" class="confirm-address-button">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: I feel like this should work but it is not...When I hit the arrow key it is closing the modal still.  I added a console.log inside the if (e instanceof MouseEvent) and it is firing when hitting a key on the keyboard.   Wondering if using a screen reader is registering all keyboard events as mouse events...

Comment: @dev_in_training updated. maybe give that a try.